# Set DateTimePicker Value from a retrieved Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm having a hard time in assigning values that came from my database,

Value to be retrieved :

```
AppointmentTime
Value = 11:00:00
Data Type = time(0)
```

I use VS 2010 to assign that value from SQL Server 2008 with a DateTimePicker..

```
DateTimePicker1
Format = HH:mm
MinDate = 1/1/1770

DateTimePicker1.Value = Appointment Time
```

It gives me an error of 'Value of 1/1/0001 11:00:00AM is not valid for Value. Value should be between MinDate and MaxDate..

I wonder why SQL Server 2008 gives a value of Date, in my Time(0) Column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this query

```
declare @x time(0);
set @x = getdate();
print cast(@x as datetime);
```

It will be give you the time with the date 01/01/1900.

So, try to cast Appointment Time to `DateTime` before set the `DateTimePicker1` value.